# Eclipse Juno Internal Web Browser unavailable (Ubuntu)

Tags: browser, ubuntu-12.04, eclipse-juno

I've installed Eclipse (Juno) on Ubuntu Precise and am unable to use Eclipse's internal web browser.  I'm getting this error:

SWT Browser control is not available

I've searched around and haven't found a solution that works.

Thanks for your help!

Mike

Comment: This applies to Indigo too (any eclipse?) and when viewing Javadoc too.

Answer (score 8):

I did find a solution which worked:

sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

I'm not sure why, though.

Mike

Comment: Thanks for the straight forward solution. Looks like eclipse runs internal browser on webkitgtk, which is nice. Tested on a headless ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux, the SWT browser widget can either use Mozilla XULRunner or Webkit [1](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux). I have had version conflicts between the web browser included in a Linux distro, XULRunner and what's accepted by SWT. Using Webkit seems an easier approach. If you have both XULRunner and Webkit installed, see [2](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserwebkitgtk) to select a specific toolkit.