# Mozilla internal web browser unavailable on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, firefox, ubuntu-12.04

I have the configuration below,

```
Ubuntu 12.04.1
Eclipse 3.7.2
JDK 1.6.0_37
Firefox 17.0 for Ubuntu - 1.0
```

"Internal browser unavailable" occurs on Eclipse,

```
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Internal browser is not available: 
No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
```

"Use internal web browser" option appears permanently disabled (greyed out) from "preferences->general->web browser",

[image: browser]

Any hints to bring back `Mozilla internal web browser`?

**@EDIT**

Using webkit1.0 instead as a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354115/eclipse-juno-internal-web-browser-unavailable-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 13.04 using Eclipse it automagically worked, I was not sure which webkit I was missing, so I installed all that seemed relevant, if someone has pinpointed which it is, please comment,

Regards,

Gabriel Medina

```
aptitude install libqt4-webkit libqt5webkit5 libqtscript4-webkit libqtwebkit4 libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```